# Save variable Python blueprints flask

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi

I have an application i have developed in order to control stuff over the internet with flask and blueprints on a Raspberry Pi. I have on the client side an android app that sends http requests and the raspberry pi with flask application as server answers. I have a scenario in which i control a fan by setting a pin to do pwm and then changing it's duty cycle to control it's speed. After i change the speed I make the app return a json message with the current duty cycle and if the fan is spinning or not (the spinning part is useless i know :) ). Problem is, i cannot save the duty cycle in a variable without it resetting every time i re-call the function that just reports the status (the one with the "/" route on it). I can't think of a way to make it do this simple and quick without saving it in files, and i dont want to complicate it with files if possible.

This is the code for the main app that has the one with the fan registered as a blueprint.

```
from flask import Flask
from scen3 import scen3_api
from scen2 import scen2_api
app = Flask(__name__)


app.register_blueprint(scen3_api, url_prefix='/scenariu/3')
app.register_blueprint(scen2_api, url_prefix='/scenariu/2')
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
```

This is the code for the second script that contains scen 2 stuff. Basically it has 2 functions after setting up the pins that return the duty cycle and the spin state on the "/" route and changes the value of the PWM by the  parameter on the "/PWMValue/" route.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify, Blueprint

scen2_api= Blueprint('scen2_api', __name__)    

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.output(18, GPIO.HIGH)

GPIO.setup(16,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(16,GPIO.LOW)

dutyCycle=0
spin=0
p = GPIO.PWM(12, 500)

p.start(float(dutyCycle))
#spin=0
@scen2_api.route("/")
def main():
    spin=0  
    if dutyCycle != 0.0:
        spin=1
return jsonify(state=str(spin),pwmvalue=str(dutyCycle))


@scen2_api.route("/PWMValue/<action>")
def action( action):

    dutyCycle=float(action)
    p.ChangeDutyCycle(float(dutyCycle))

    return jsonify(state=str(spin),pwmvalue=str(dutyCycle))
```

Every time i call the function with the report function it returns me 0 duty cycle and spin. how can i fix this, but still make this behave the same preferabbly without using files? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`spin` and `dutyCycle` are *locals* in the `main` and `action` functions, respectively. All variables you assign to automatically are. Use the `global` keyword to tell Python to treat them otherwise:

```
@scen2_api.route("/")
def main():
    global spin
    spin=0
    if dutyCycle != 0.0:
        spin=1
    return jsonify(state=str(spin), pwmvalue=str(dutyCycle))


@scen2_api.route("/PWMValue/<action>")
def action( action):
    global dutyCycle
    dutyCycle = float(action)
    p.ChangeDutyCycle(float(dutyCycle))

    return jsonify(state=str(spin), pwmvalue=str(dutyCycle))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have a scope problem and you may have indentation problems... but your problem is scope-related:

In `action(action)` you're setting a variable called `dutyCycle` that is local to the `action` function, I believe you're expecting to change the "global" variable. To understand what's going on, take a look at the following:

```
>>> g = 34
>>> g
34
>>> def f(n):
...     g = n
...     print g
...
>>> f(3)
3
>>> g
34
>>>
```

`f` changes its local `g`, not the global that you'd be expecting. Take a look at this blog post of [understanding Python's execution model](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/02/14/drastically-improve-your-python-understanding-pythons-execution-model/). You can just head down to "Blocks and Scope", but I suggest to read it all.

Back to your code:

- There is no need for the globals `dutyCycle` and `spin`
- Put all GPIO initialization in a separate function/route